# Неверное отображение box-shadow при использовании translate3d

Tags: javascript, css3, google-chrome, css-animation, angular4

Проблема при использовании `box-shadow` совместно с `translate3d`.

Возникает белый круг вокруг тени. Хорошо заметно, если используем цветной фон.

Проблема возникает в последней версии хрома (*Chrome 61.0.3163.100*).

Посмотреть можно на [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Stepan_Kasyanenko/0a7r9k25/).

```css
.content {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #bcbcff;
  height: 200px;
}

.slide {
  position: relative;
  left: calc(50% - 50px);
  top: calc(50% - 50px);
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);
}

.shadow {
  box-shadow: 12px 37px 60px 5px rgba(92, 95, 101, 0.28);
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #f6f6f6;
  transition:box-shadow 300ms linear;
}
.shadow:hover{
   box-shadow: 12px 37px 60px 5px rgba(92, 95, 101, 1);
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div class="slide">
    <div class="shadow">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Что пытался:

1. Убрать `translate3d`. Без него прекрасно работает. Но, к сожалению, не могу убрать, т.к. использую сторонний слайдер ([ngx-slick](https://github.com/devmark/ngx-slick/)). А он делает прокручивание слайдов с помощью `translate3d`.
2. Задать фон родительскому элементу (в моем примере `.slide`). Тоже работает, но возникает проблема с анимацией тени. Белый круг появляется, потом исчезает.

Какие решения видеть бы хотелось:

1. С помощью `css` или\и изменяя структуру `HTML`. Могу менять все, что внутри `.slide`.
2. Альтернативный способ создания тени с возможностью анимации.

Какие решения видеть бы **НЕ** хотелось:

1. Использование другой библиотеки для слайдера.
2. Изменение внутренностей `ngx-slick`.

Ссылка на живой [проект](http://cowrite.decodeapps.io/#/). Карусель в самом низу.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Поскольку как исправить не придумал, решил отображать тень по другому.

Вместо тени будем использовать псевдоэлемент `:after` с размытием.

Пример на [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Stepan_Kasyanenko/0a7r9k25/).

```css
.content {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #bcbcff;
  height: 200px;
}

.slide {
  position: relative;
  left: calc(50% - 50px);
  top: calc(50% - 50px);
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);
}

.shadow {
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #f6f6f6;
  z-index: 2;
}

.shadow:after {
  content: " ";
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  top: 37px;
  left: 12px;
  background-color: rgba(92, 95, 101, 0.28);
  transition: background-color 300ms linear;
  z-index: -1;
  filter: blur(13px);
}

.shadow:hover:after {
  background-color: rgba(92, 95, 101, 0.9);
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div class="slide">
    <div class="shadow">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```